# Installs to Root of C: Instead of \Program Files\

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I built an application and created an installer project for it using Visual Studio.  Everywhere I've ever installed the application, it works perfectly, except on one particular 2008 R2 server.

Regardless of what folder is specified in the installer, the program always installs to the root of C: on one server.  Works perfectly everywhere else.

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Thanks

This is a terminal server.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: as in "c:\applicationname" instead of "C:\program files\applicationname"?

Comment: Check out the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir` reg string value  to make sure it's "C:\Program Files"

Comment: Does "installer project" mean a VS Deployment project? What's your project's File System Application Folder DefaultLocation property value?

Comment: Peter: It actually dropped the executable, dlls, etc direclty in c:\ and creates the program's subfolders as c:\folder

Comment: Peter: The registry key is not present.

Comment: Dour: Yes, a VS Deployment project.  The default location is set to [ProgramFiles64Folder]\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]   (Yes, this is a 64-bit server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method to investigate the installation is to create a [verbose log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300) of it, the log will contain all required information regarding the installation paths. What are their default values, what changes them, etc...

If have problems parsing the log post a link to it so I can download and have a look over it,
[reading a Windows Installer verbose log](http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2010/02/05/how-to-read-a-windows-installer-verbose-log.aspx) is quite easy.

**EDIT**: From the log linked log, at line 620, you can get this "*Machine policy value 'EnableUserControl' is 0*". Because [the EnableUserControl policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is enabled the property storing your installation path ("TARGETDIR") is not passed from the UI sequence to the execute sequence of the installation (see line 622 "*Ignoring disallowed property TARGETDIR*"), making the installer to reset it.

You need to set this policy back to value "1", by editing the registry mentioned in the linked article from MSDN.

Comment: See the edit from my answer, with the solution. Let me know it works

Comment: Thanks for your responses and answer.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: My pleasure Brad, glad I could help you.